# How to keep apache as front and tomcat as back end?

Tags: apache, tomcat

Basically i want my tomcat to run on PORT 80 how do i do that because whenever i have to access something then i have to go for [localhost:8080/resource](http://link) but instead i want to use the link as only [localhost/resource](http://linkk) how do i achieve this?

Currently on my machine apache is running on 800 port and tomcat on 8080.

Comment: Do you want to run Tomcat on port 80, or run Apache HTTP Server on port 80 and forward requests to Tomcat?

Comment: I want to run tomcat on 80. let it be direct or via apache no problem in that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In server.xml find the element that reads

```
Connector port="8080"
```

and change it to 80. Save and restart tomcat.
Just make sure that apache is running on port 800 otherwise it will now clash with tomcat.

Comment: Your absolutely sure that you dont allready have some kind of other service running on port 80? Something like IIS perhaps or even Skype. Skype has a nasty habit of taking over port 80. In Skype: Tools>Options menu Click on the Advanced settings>Connection section. Uncheck Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections. Failing that open up a commandline and do a netstat -a or even try netstat -b so you can see the application that started listening on the ports.

Comment: This won't work on Linux without additional modifications, you can't bind < 1024

Answer (score 5):

it seems you are looking for something called [Reverse Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). Using Reverse Proxy, you will have

1. apache on 80 port
2. tomcat on 8080 port

so when access http://xxx.test.com/resource, the request first go though apache, apache then pass the request tomcat, tomcat do the corresponding things and return response to client.
have a look at:

1. http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies
2. mod_jk: http://tomcat.apache.org/download-connectors.cgi

Answer (score 3):

Tomcat documentation has a HOWTO for this.

http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html

Its a good practice to never expose Tomcat directly internet. You can use Apache for serving static content and send only those requests to tomcat that need dynamic content.

Answer (score 1):

To modify the HTTP port for Tomcat, modify the configuration file `server.xml` (located in Tomcat's `conf` directory). Find the HTTP connector element (that is currently configured to port 8080), change the port number to 80, and restart Tomcat.

Note that this is not going to work if any other running service is currently bound on port 80.

Comment: Then update your question with this information, and describe with more detail what kind of changes you have tried in the configuration file, and what errors / problems you encountered with that setup.